# Screen with RecyclerView scrolled to bottom when screen is opened

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `Fragment` with a `RecyclerView`. When the screen is loaded, it is automatically scrolled to the end of the `RecyclerView`. How to disable this?

Code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sleep_month, container, false);
    tfSegoeui = Typeface.createFromAsset(getResources().getAssets(), "fonts/segoeui.ttf");
    tfSegoeuiBold = Typeface.createFromAsset(getResources().getAssets(), "fonts/SEGOEUIB.TTF");

    fabAdd = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fabAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), AddSleepActivity.class);
            getActivity().startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });
    recyclerCategoryList = new ArrayList<>();

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mAdapter =  new RecyclerSleepAdapter(recyclerCategoryList);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    prepareListData();
}

private void prepareListData() {

    //recyclerCategoryList = new ArrayList<>();

    SleepDataModel listData = new SleepDataModel("Fri,Jan 7 11.28PM - 7.00AM",75,"7 Hrs 32 Mins");
    recyclerCategoryList.add(listData);

    listData = new SleepDataModel("Thu,Jan 6 11.00PM - 5.45AM",30,"6 Hrs 45 Mins");
    recyclerCategoryList.add(listData);

    listData = new SleepDataModel("Wed,Jan 5 10.50PM - 7.00AM", 60,"8 Hrs 10 Mins");
    recyclerCategoryList.add(listData);

    listData = new SleepDataModel("Tue,Jan 4 10.00PM - 5.00AM",50, "5 Hrs 30 Mins" );
    recyclerCategoryList.add(listData);

    listData = new SleepDataModel("Mon,Jan 3 9.50PM - 6.00AM",50, "7 Hrs 15 Mins" );
    recyclerCategoryList.add(listData);

    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: @VygintasB Please see updated question

Answer (score 1):

It's because you populate your datalist after you set adaper and recyclerview is hsowing last added row. Try calling `prepareListData()` before `mAdapter =  new RecyclerSleepAdapter(recyclerCategoryList);`

Ofcourse delete this line from prepareListData(): `mAdaper.notifyDataSetChanged` as your adapter at this point is null

Comment: `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` throws an Exception as `mAdapter` is initialized after `prepareListData()` is called.

Comment: @JasmineThomas Is recyclerview still scrolled to bottom?

Comment: Yes. Still scrolled to bottom

Comment: This is not default behaviour.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @JasmineThomas If you would provide full imlementation of recyclerview i might have a look, but for now it's hard to say what problem it is

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);` after calling     `notifyDataSetChanged()`.